# Error al tratar de correr mi app con android studio en mi celular

Tags: android, android-studio

Cuando quiero correr mi app en mi celular desde Android Studio me da un error.

Log del error:

> 01/25 12:30:48: Launching app
>   $ adb shell am start -n "com.example.regalodiana/com.example.regalodiana.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.regalodiana/com.example.regalodiana.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.regalodiana/.MainActivity }
>   Error type 3
>   Error: Activity class {com.example.regalodiana/com.example.regalodiana.MainActivity} does not exist.
>
> Error while Launching activity

Desde la máquina virtual corre perfecto, solo es a la hora de querer correr la aplicación de mi celular.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que trates de desinstalar la app de tu celular primero si ya la tenías instalada.

Comment: si la app la subes a tu emulador funciona sin problema?

Comment: si en el emulador sin problemas, en APK si me funciona normal en el celular.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que no tienes creada la clase MainActivity, y alguna otra clase la está llamando. Por lo cual no puede abrirse.

O si tu aplicación inicia con otra clase que hayas creado (por ejemplo login), verifica que ésta realmente se abre primero en el archivo AndroidManifest, en lugar de la de MainAcitivity (que en tu caso no existe)

[image: archivo androidManifest]

Comment: Bienvenida gracias por el apoyo, considera que el código de tus respuestas vaya como texto y no como imagen por favor

Comment: Bienvenida Judy, tu respuesta es útil, pero considera convertir la imagen a texto, tal como lo sugiere @Aprendiz.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y supongo que ha de ser un error del android studio o no se porque haciendo el proyecto una APK si la puedo correr en mi celular sin problemas

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que te refieres a que la aplicación funciona sin problema desde el emulador (avd) y no desde el dispositivo fisico.

Este problema:

> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=com.example.regalodiana/.MainActivity } Error type 3 Error:
>   Activity class
>   {com.example.regalodiana/com.example.regalodiana.MainActivity} does
>   not exist.

Aunque menciona que la Activity no existe, puedes tenerla definida pero el error se puede deber a varias causas:

- Primeramente debes descartar un problema con el cable, asegura que funciona sin problema para que el ADB pueda subir sin problema el .apk a tu dispositivo. Incluso puedes reiniciar tu computadora ya que podría tenerse un problrma con el proceso adb.exe.
- Este problema puede ser causado también por un problema de sincronización, por lo tanto te sugiero realizar un `Clean` y `Build`, o eliminar el directorio `/build` de tu proyecto y volver a construir el proyecto.

Comment: gracias y si creo que tal vez sea el cable o algo con el Android Studio porque el APK lo instalo en mi celular y funciona perfecto

Comment: En ocasiones el cable falla y no permite subir el .apk a tu dispositivo, aunque en este caso parece más problema del proceso ADB.